# How to install aarch64-none-elf on the raspberry pi

Tags: bare-metal

I have tried installing aarch64-none-elf on my raspberry pi 3B+ from the [arm website](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/downloads) when I extract it, I can't run the executable files in it.

Here's the error:
`bash: ./aarch64-none-elf-gcc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Is there any way to fix that error, or download it from another source.

`file aarch64-none-elf-gcc` returns
`` aarch64-none-elf-gcc: cannot open `aarch64-none-elf-gcc' (No such file or directory) ``

Comment: Please edit in the output from `file aarch64-none-elf-gcc` and  `file $(which file)` (the last one is to demonstrate that you are, or are not, running a 64-bit OS).

Comment: I've just realised it's 32 bit instead of 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've just realised it's 32 bit instead of 64 bit

You can't run 64-bit software on a 32-bit system, obviously.  The 64-bit version of RpiOS should run fine on a 3B+, since while I'm not sure if you can compile 64-bit binaries on a 32-bit platform (I'd think so, but could not find discussion of such in a quick online search), that compiler does not have a 32-bit host version for linux.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need to install the 64 bit version of the os, and then I will try it. I didn't realise that it was the 32 bit version